# Extensions manually installed (using "load unpacked") vanish after closing and relaunching Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I find myself forced to install the same extension again and again everytime I need it because Chrome systematically removes it. How can I tell Chrome to stop doing that?

Comment: Which extension is it?

Comment: Can you provide more information?

Comment: What other information is required? The specific addon is irrelevant, as this is a characteristic of how Chrome treats unpacked addons.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you generally cannot.

Manually loaded add-ons are intentionally force-removed when Chrome restarts. This is done to [prevent applications from end-running around Chrome's add-on security requirements.](https://blog.chromium.org/2013/11/protecting-windows-users-from-malicious.html)

All add-ons as of Chrome 33 on Windows and 44 on Mac have to be distributed through Chrome's marketplace and no other location. The "load unpacked" functionality is intended purely for developers, not for the actual users of the add-on.